# Counterexample to the double integral computational theorem when the double integral existence assumption is dropped?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

To make things simple, consider the simplest case of the double integral computational theorem. Throughout any phrase involving integrability is in the Riemannian sense.

Let $[a, b], [c, d] \subset \mathbb{R},$ let $Q := [a, b] \times [c, d],$ and let $f: Q \to \mathbb{R}$ be bounded. If $\underset{Q}{\iint} f$ exists, and if $\int_{a}^{b} f(x, y) dx$ exists for every $y \in [c, d]$ and is integrable on $[c, d],$ then 
$$\underset{Q}{\iint} f = \int_{c}^{d}\int_{a}^{b} f(x, y) dx dy.$$

I just noticed a thing that I hardly ever noticed, that is, what is a counterexample to this theorem if we drop the assumption of the existence of the integral of $f$ over $Q$?  It is intuitively plausible that we MAY just compute separately the one-dimensional integrals and then conclude that, yes, the double integral also exists?

Comment: And by "integrable" you mean what? Riemann or Lebesgue?

Comment: Hey thank you. In Riemannian sense, I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exercise: Find a dense subset $E$ of $Q$ such that $E$ intersects each horizontal line and each vertical line in a finite set.

Given the exercise, set $f = \chi_E.$ Then $f$ is not Riemann integrable on $Q.$ But

$$ \int_{c}^{d}\int_{a}^{b} f(x, y)\, dx\, dy = \int_{a}^{b}\int_{c}^{d} f(x, y) \,dy \,dx =0.$$

Comment: Yes, continuity. Thank you.